# Ruby Program not reading all lines in files

Tags: ruby, io

I am new to ruby and have the following code that reads in a file, then places the symbols separated by a '|' sign into different attributes of a Struc data type:

```
Song = Struct.new(:title, :name, :length)
song_file = File.new("songdata.txt")
songs = []

song_file.each_line do |line|
    file, length, name, title = line.chomp.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
    songs << Song.new(title, name, length)
end

p songs
```

The file songdata.txt contains the following txt:

```
/jazz/j00132.mp3  | 3:45 | Fats     Waller     | Ain't Misbehavin'
/jazz/j00319.mp3  | 2:58 | Louis    Armstrong  | Wonderful World
/bgrass/bg0732.mp3| 4:09 | Strength in Numbers | Texas Red
```

However, when I go to print the array songs, it only contains the first line of the text file. Any thoughts on to why this is?

Comment: I ran this exact code and this exact input file on my machine, but got all three lines. Are you sure it's misbehaving? What version of ruby do you have?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the input you are using? Works as it should for me.

Comment: 2.3.0 - And yes, saying that the other indexes are nil

Comment: What do you guys use for txt files?

Comment: that code looks fine. must be something else going on.

Comment: use to do what with txt files? i do what you posted above for what you're trying to do.

Comment: As in any particular applications? Just using notes on my mac and was wondering if that had anything to do with it ... I know it shouldn't though

Comment: I edited the text file using vim on Linux. It might be due to different line-endings, but I doubt it. To test it, within the loop print the first line to check what it is. 
Here is my output:
http://pastebin.com/P2vgKiBY

Comment: Alright got it working, just recreated the file and now it works as it should ... thanks for the support guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be related to line endings. Ruby seems to handle Windows and Unix line endings all right, but would only read the first line when you change your file's line ending to OSX's ("Mac OS 9" in SublimeText).

Change line endings of your `songdata.txt` to Unix or Windows.

Comment: Thanks for that - when I created the file via TextEdit it didn't work. But it worked when I used TextWrangler to create the file as it's default is Unix

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arr = []
File.open('songdata.txt', 'r') do |song_file|
    song_file.each_line do |detail|
      arr =  detail.split(' | ')
      title = arr[0].split(/\s*\|\s*/)
      length = arr[1]
      artist = arr[2]
      name = arr[3]
      #now you can do anything as per requirement
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was due to line endings. I post this just to show you how you can use `map` for this use case. It also uses `__END__` and `DATA` to mix ruby code and test data in a single ruby script. Good for testing such cases.

```
Song = Struct.new(:title, :name, :length)
song_file = DATA

songs = song_file.each_line.map do |line|
    file, length, name, title = line.chomp.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
    Song.new(title, name, length)
end

p songs.size
__END__
/jazz/j00132.mp3  | 3:45 | Fats     Waller     | Ain't Misbehavin'
/jazz/j00319.mp3  | 2:58 | Louis    Armstrong  | Wonderful World
/bgrass/bg0732.mp3| 4:09 | Strength in Numbers | Texas Red
```

By using `map` you can avoid defining the empty array before iterating the file.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said before for similar questions, you probably should not be doing the parsing yourself, but rather using a CSV library to do it for you.  CSV = Comma Separated Values, but there is support for delimiters other than commas, and pipes are common.

Ruby has a built-in CSV library, and using it, you can compare the results of your approach and the CSV approach with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

Song = Struct.new(:title, :name, :length)
SONG_FILESPEC = 'songdata.txt'

def read_records_regex  # OP's original approach
  songs = []
  File.new(SONG_FILESPEC).each_line do |line|
      file, length, name, title = line.chomp.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
      songs << Song.new(title, name, length)
  end
  songs
end

require 'csv'
def read_records_csv  # alternate CSV approach
  songs = []
  CSV.foreach(SONG_FILESPEC, col_sep: '|') do |fields|
    fields.map!(&:strip)
    file, length, name, title = fields
    songs << Song.new(title, name, length)
  end
  songs
end

puts read_records_regex
puts '-' * 79
puts read_records_csv
```

Output:

```
#<struct Song title="Ain't Misbehavin'", name="Fats     Waller", length="3:45">
#<struct Song title="Wonderful World", name="Louis    Armstrong", length="2:58">
#<struct Song title="Texas Red", name="Strength in Numbers", length="4:09">
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#<struct Song title="Ain't Misbehavin'", name="Fats     Waller", length="3:45">
#<struct Song title="Wonderful World", name="Louis    Armstrong", length="2:58">
#<struct Song title="Texas Red", name="Strength in Numbers", length="4:09">
```

Note that the data file should probably not have spaces if they are to be discarded.

There are CSV gems that are more sophisticated than Ruby's built in support, but this case is simple enough that Ruby's is fine.